# Html video not pausing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to exit the video but the audio keep playing in the background. i have tried to add .pause(); to the javascript but it did not work

```
<div id="video-frame">
    <span id="video-frame-hide" class="fa fa-times"></span>
    <div class="video-frame-container">
        <div class="video-frame-scaler">
            <iframe id="embed-video" src="Videos/Female Upper Body.MP4" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

videoFrameHide.on('click', () => {
            
            videoFrame.css({
                'opacity': '0',
                'visibility': 'hidden',
                'z-index': '0' 
            });
   

            embedVideo.prop('src', embedVideo.prop(
                'src'));

        });
```

Comment: `videoFrameHide.on` this is not valid JavaScript. Perhaps jQuery. Have you included that library?

Comment: Why do you use `<iframe>` instead of the [`<video>` element?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: No i have  not included it

Comment: You cannot use a library syntax without including it. I mean, you don't need jQuery, you can do everything in pure JS - just saying.

Comment: Only https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video element has play/pause methods. Please take a look https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp
Also, it is possible to remove iframe from DOM to free all related resources and stop the video. For example, `embedVideo.remove()`